# Domain Services vs Entity Methods in Domain Model

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, domain-driven-design

I know the difference between domain and application services. But can't really see the difference between methods in domain entities and domain services:/

I have a game, that has `State`, `Players` etc.. It also has methods like `AddPlayer`, `MoveLeft`, `Jump`. Where these methods goes? Should I create naked `KOGame` with only properties and then `KOGameServices` with functionality?

Uncle Bob in his article [here](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) wrote *"An entity can be an object with methods, or it can be a set of data structures and functions."*

I don't even want to mention that methods like `Move` or `Jump` **will have to** be also in App Services, in `KOGameAPI` - cause those methods are needed by UI (through interfaces of course).

Here is my class:

```
public class KOGame
{
    public GameState State { get; set; }
    public IList<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public int PlayersCount;

    public KOGame()
    {
        State = GameState.New;
        PlayersCount = 2;
        Players = new List<Player>();
    }

    public void AddPlayer(Player player)
    {
    }

    public bool MoveRight(int id)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool MoveLeft(int id)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool Jump(int id)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, wrap up my question: What methods goes to Domain Services and what methods goes to Domain Entities? Having for example `Class1` class, when should I create `Class1Services` class?

**EDIT:**
Just a quick explanation why I choose `DDD`:
I want to create cross platform app and I want to have single layer common for every platform. I choose `C#`, cause with help of `Xamarin` I can easily implement single domain model and even services for every platform. I just got stuck at deciding what methods should go to Services and what as a part of entities in `Domain Model`

Comment: Onion architecture, DDD, Domain services, Applicacion services... For the architecture of a videogame? I think your are going to the wrong approach.

Comment: @jlvaquero +1, for some slow-paced, browser-based games it could be an option, but here it seems like a real-time game so I definitely agree DDD is not a good fit.

Comment: @jlvaquero Alright, but the question is: What methods goes to Domain Services and what methods goes to Domain Entities? Having for example Class1 class, when should I create Class1Services class?

Comment: @guillaume31 don't know what do you mean by "real-time game"? but it will be a mobile game, like Chess, Connect-four, more like "Turn-based game". I want to use C#(via Xamarin) and write single model for all platforms. So my POINT is I want to have common dll, common domain - and that is because I want to use Onion Architecture.

Comment: My bad, "Jump" made me think it was some kind of platform or combat game.

Comment: Me too. But I still thik that DDD is not a good choice. For example physics or IA will break your aggregate encapsulation and responsibilities.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain "physics or IA will break your aggregate encapsulation and responsibilities"? I'm not sure I understand. What's IA btw?

Comment: @jlvaquero I forgot to tag you. Again, can you explain me why DDD (Onion Architecture to be exact) is not good for cross-platform apps like that ?

Comment: I meant AI. Artificial intelligence.

Comment: DDD is not good for videogames because how objects need to interact betwen them and how they need to expose their data.

Comment: @jlvaquero It depends. As I said, a non-realtime game can be more like a state machine that behaves like a regular business application. A browser-based 2 player chess game, for instance, could have no IA and no physics.

Comment: @guillaume31 I was talking about games where players interact more with board then themselves. Like chess, connect four, tic tac toe etc.. So the `Game` object has `Board`, `List<Player>`, `GameState` etc. I want to create such game cross-platform, so onion arch. was my first choice. Theoretically, in games I mentioned before, in single player mode - there is a little bit `AI`. What architecture would you recommend me? or at least direction where should I go with my research?

Comment: @AntwanReno If it's a one-tier client-only application with no user collaboration whatsoever but the player just plays against the AI, I wouldn't bother with DDD.

Comment: @guillaume31 Well, the thing is, I don't specify whether it will be single, multi or whatever player. I'm planning to build single player w AI, multiplayer through the server or p2p, I don't know yet. Maybe kinda both... that's why I wanted to use DDD. What's the other way to do it? I mean, if not DDD than what?

Comment: Game development is a whole other beast than line of business app development. There's even a dedicated SE site for it : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: But maybe you're putting the cart before the horse trying to specify an architecture when you haven't even determined the exact features of your game yet...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If, to acomplish a use case, you need, at domain level, coordinate 2 or more aggregates you put the coordination logic in domain services calling aggregate methods. If just one aggregate is needed then no domain service is involved. Just call aggregate method from app service.

Comment: One question, Why did you changed _entity_ to _aggregate_?

Comment: Because in DDD you should have aggregates that could be one or more entities that need to be consistent and aggregate is the term.

Comment: @AntwanReno I suggest you read up on DDD a bit more, especially the blue or the red book are must-reads IMO. Domain Services is one of the basics that they cover.

Comment: I agree with  guillaume31. And keep in mind that DDD and Onion Architecture is not the same.

Answer (score 8):

**If a method logically belongs to an entity, put it there. If there isn't any entity where the method would make sense, put it in a (stateless!) domain service.**

For example, a method to move a player should be on the player entity - it feels natural to have it there, because it *modifies that specific player*.

On the other hand, a method to e.g. calculate the score difference of two players could be implemented as a domain service.

Comment: but both Domain Entities and Domain Services should be on the same level, right? Just different classes? (for example, in Visual Studio - both should be in the same project `MyApp.Domain`, right?

Comment: Yes, both belong to the *domain model*.